# Bash/C shell: Are there any drawbacks about escaping all characters of a file path?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, escaping, filepath

**Are there any drawbacks about escaping all characters of a Unix file path ?** By drawbacks, I mean: limitation of any kind, cases where a file path could not be interpreted by a Unix shell, etc..

Example:

```
/my/path/to/file.txt
```

becomes

```
\/\m\y\/\p\a\t\h\/\t\o\/\f\i\l\e\.\t\x\t
```

**Notes:**

- Readability is not an issue here since it is for automation.
- Shell: Bash Shell and C Shell

**Reason:**

I am writing a small Python application to transcode images and video using various command lines on Unix's Bash Shell (FFMPEG, Handbrake, FFPROBE, ImageMagick's identify and convert). Some of the files paths have spaces, brakets characters, etc... File names with such characters usually break command lines in those tools if those characters are not escaped properly. I would prefer to find a solution that applies well in general rather than have to  escapes only a few characters such as spaces, brackets, etc. Especially in the context where I have not control over the files names and that I try to make my application as robust as possible when dealing with files names with special characters. Hence the solution of escaping everything.

**Results:**

I have escaped all characters and I have not encountered any problem except in case of Python OS modules/functions which already handle file name for specific OSes (escaping all characters is a problem in this case but I expected it). Therefore, I would say that escaping all characters does not have any drawbacks (except the case I mentioned previously).

Regards,

symbion

Comment: is there *any* reason to do this?

Comment: use `'`, `"`, or python commands that expect arguments in an array. escaping is not the right way to go...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I agree with ' and " and array for python commands expecting it. But why is escaping all characters not the way to go ? Do you have any example ?

Comment: why do you need a shell? Python `subprocess` module doesn't require any shell to run a subprocess. You don't need to escape anything just provide a list of arguments: `subprocess.check_call(['ffmpeg', 'arg1', 'arg2'])`

Answer (score 2):

The example you've given won't work because in general a single character preceded by a backslash does not escape the character, but introduces a new meaning. `\n` for example is not `n` escaped, but the newline character.

Another way of escaping special characters is to enclose everything in quotes, e.g.

```
"/my/path/to/file.txt"
```

With this you only need to escape the quote character `"`, i.e. `\"`. Alternatively, you can use a single quote character around the path, e.g.

```
'/my/path/to/file.txt'
```

Same applies here, if the path contains a `'`, you need to escape it.

Comment: no, in the shell `\n` is not a newline character. try `echo \na`

Answer (score 1):

What you care about in a program like this are two things:

1. Functionality
2. Readability

The first point is obvious - You need the correct string to be passed from one program to the other. In Bash there are only two ways you can write *absolutely any* filename in a script. Given for example a filename like this:

```
$ echo -n $'\a\b\E\f\r\t\v\'"\360\240\202\211 \n' | uniname -pcb
UTF-32   encoded as     glyph   name
000007   07                     BELL
000008   08                     BACKSPACE
00001B   1B                     ESCAPE
00000C   0C                     FORM FEED (FF)
00000D   0D                     CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)
000009   09                     CHARACTER TABULATION
00000B   0B                     LINE TABULATION
000027   27             '      APOSTROPHE
000022   22             "      QUOTATION MARK
020089   F0 A0 82 89          Unknown character in range CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B
000020   20                     SPACE
00000A   0A                     LINE FEED (LF)
```

There are five ways to write strings in Bash, one of which (`$""`) is not relevant for this purpose:

- <strike>Literal string</strike> with escape characters. There's [no way to include a *literal* newline this way](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Escape-Character), so that's out. Example:

  ```
  $ foo=bar
  $ baz
  No command 'baz' found, did you mean: ...
  $ foo=bar\
  > baz
  $ echo "$foo"
  barbaz
  $ foo=bar\nbaz
  $ echo "$foo"
  barnbaz
  $ foo=bar\\nbaz
  $ echo "$foo"
  bar\nbaz
  ```
- <strike>Single-quoted string</strike>. These [can't contain other single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes), so they're out.
- [Double-quoted string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes). You can put anything in these, but you have to escape *some* characters if you want their literal representation - Simply preceding every character with a backslash is not likely to produce the result you want. Also, complicated characters like `BELL` will have to be included as a *literal*, making it effectively invisible to the person reading the script or output.
- [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), shown above. This can also contain any character, but you can escape special characters to make the string more readable.

Of the two methods, it's pretty clear that if you want to print *any* filename you should use ANSI-C Quoting if you don't know what the string might contain. But if you want to always use the "minimal" escaping, you can print the value using `printf %q` - Compare:

```
$ printf %q $'word'
word
$ printf %q $'space separated'
space\ separated
$ printf %q $'newline\nembedded'
$'newline\nembedded'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you asked, but might be the best solution given the added reason: python's `pipes` module has a function called `quote`, which you can import and which quotes pathnames for shell commands:

```
$ python
...
>>> from pipes import quote
>>> quote('filename')
'filename'
>>> quote('filename with "funny"\tcharacters')
'\'filename with "funny"\tcharacters\''
>>> >>> quote("filename with 'single quotes'")
'\'filename with \'"\'"\'single quotes\'"\'"\'\''
>>>
```